# Setting a random number of characters to an array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make an array of 16 characters with the next conditions:
Between 1 to 3 characters must be a W.
2 characters must be X
And the rest need to be O.
How can I do it?

Comment: Just do it? `char[] chars = new char[] {'W','W','X','X','O','O','O','O','O','O','O','O','O','O','O','O'};`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a array which can be randomly initialized based on the conditions you mentioned. The random number generator which is present in the java.util.Random package is quite useful in such cases. Below is the code which can be used.

```
    Random ran = new Random();
    int countW = ran.nextInt(3);
    int insertCountW = 0;
    int insertCountX = 0;
    char[] c = new char[16];
    while(insertCountW != countW){
        int pos = ran.nextInt(16);
        c[pos] = 'W';
        insertCountW++;
    }
    while(insertCountX != 2){
        int pos = ran.nextInt(16);
       if(c[pos] == 0){
           c[pos] = 'X';
           insertCountX++;
       }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        if(c[i] == 0){
            c[i] = 'O';
        }
    }
```

The following document from the Oracle document might be useful https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html to know more about the package. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please do follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names should be written in camelCase. So no underscores.